# Run away array Trying to replace text with vaule in array

Tags: python, python-2.7

My python doesn't stop. I have and array that i can call "hdd[1]" etc but when i try to have the array replace text found withe the correct value in the array each time it finds it (stepping up one place in the array each time) it doesn't stop. It just makes the file and keeps going

```
def cleanup():  
    infile = open('HDDprices-pre.txt')
    outfile = open('HDDprices.txt', 'wt')
    while 1:
        for s in hdd:
            line = infile.readline()
            if not line: break
            line = line.replace("('","")
            line = line.replace("Decimal('",s)
            line = line.replace("'),","\n")
            line = line.replace("'))","")
            outfile.write(line)
        else:
            break
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
    os.remove('HDDprices-pre.txt') #erase pre file
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it just uses the first value in the array". Maybe it only has one value. Try printing it. And I didn't tell you to remove the break, since you seem to have thought that you needed it originally. I have no idea whether or not you need it. That's up to you. And it doesn't make sense to delete the input file when you're just testing the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `else` clause of the `for` loop properly. It only executes if the `for` loop exits in the usual way. By breaking out of the `for` loop with `break` the `else` clause will be skipped, and the infinite `while` loop will continue.

Why not get rid of the `while` loop and the `else` clause and just use the `for` loop?

An example of the behavior of the `else` clause:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5: break;
    print i,
else:
    print "else clause"  # will not execute because of the break

print

for i in range(10):
    print i,
else:
    print "else clause"  # will execute because loop exited normally
```

Output:

```
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 else clause
```

Comment: I didn't know [`for` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) had an `else` clause!

Comment: @KurzedMetal Strange but true! It's a python thing. [This example](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) shows the kind of thing it's used for. Just remember that it only executes on normal termination, not when the loop is exited with `break`.

Comment: @user2379600 I don't understand what you're saying and it's not really possible to properly read python code without the indentation. You should edit your question instead. And you don't need the `else` clause at all. Just get rid of it.